# meteor app - is there a way to create observable objects

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I have the following handler, returning a "contributor" record:

```
Template["IntroductionWizard_Step_1"].helpers({
  contributor: function(n) {
    return ContributorCollection.findOne({contributorName: ""});
  }
});
```

This record is being used in a reactive template:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control-element" value="{{contributor.contributorName}}"
```

As I understand, the reason for this template to track changes to this record is because it came from a reactive source.
What I was wondering is whether it would make sense to create an actual Contributor object, and return that instead of just a record. But, if I was to do that, this object would not be observed for changes, or would it?
Another words, can a more traditional object-oriented approach be used with meteor, having such Model objects as observable and reactive (two-way bindings) as those Collection records?

Comment: Are you asking: "how do I create a two-way binding"?

Comment: I think - I am. What I see in Meteor is reactive data sources in a form of minimomgo cursors. I'm trying to understand if it would make sense to transform single records, returned by the findOne() method into reactive/observable objects, which could have their own methods: Person = PeopleCollection.findOne(); and - if findOne() returns nothing:  Person.firstName = "Jon";  Person.LastName = "Smith";  Person.fullName = lastName + firstName; Person.save(). Something like object-orieted / ORM approach. Does this make any practical sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want – Javascript is a prototype based, so it's enough to get the right prototype and modify it.

To enhance behavior of collection element, you need to use `transform` method:

```
Contributor = function(doc) {
  _.extend(this, doc); // initialize object with contents of doc
  ...
};

Contributors = new Meteor.Collection('contributors', {
  transform: function(doc) {
    return new Contributor(doc);
  },
});
```

Now you can add methods to contributor's prototype:

```
_.extend(Contributor.prototype, {
  someFunction: function() {...},
  otherFunction: function() {...},
  ...
});
```

If you want to adjust collection methods, it's even simpler:

```
Contributors._findOne = Contributors.findOne;

Contributors.findOne = function() {
  var contributor = Contributors._findOne.apply(this, arguments);
  if(!contributor) {
    // initialize and save new contributor
    ...
  }
  return contributor;
};
```

With these techniques you can inject the desired behavior to collection and its elements.